# print dictionary value based on another value?

Tags: python, json

How to print the string of "value" only for id: "resolution" ??

Here in this case I want to print the value "Fixed"

```
customFields: {
 string: [
 {
 id: "device_type",
 value: "iPhone 6"
 },
 {
 id: "os_version",
 value: "iOS 10.x"
 },
 {
 id: "rabbit_build",
 value: "2.11.llyu"
 },
 {
 id: "resolution",
 value: "Fixed"
 },
```

My Python code is

```
for ib in data['documents']:
sid = ib['id']
tit = ib['title']
stat = ib['status']
nstep = ib['next_step']['action']
requester = ib['requesterIdentity']
resolution = ib['customFields']['string']
print(sid, tit, stat, nstep, requester, resolution)
```

The output prints all the ids and values rather I want to print "value" only of id: "resolution"

Comment: Invalid `dict` syntax for Python

Comment: Please don't change your whole question so heavily after people already answered, you should have use comments to correct yourself. This makes your post hardly understandable for future references / searches.

Comment: Yes you did and asked people to check your updated python code which is not actual python code and you forgot to define `data`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward, but should work:

```
for ib in data['documents']:
    sid = ib['id']
    tit = ib['title']
    stat = ib['status']
    nstep = ib['next_step']['action']
    requester = ib['requesterIdentity']
    for item in ib['customFields']['string']:
        if item['id'] == "resolution":
           resolution = item['string']
```

Sure, since "string" is a list of dictionaries you can't get specific values without looping through all dictionaries of this list. I'd also recommend you to change this list into a dictionary, so your json structure will look like this:

```
string: {
 "device_type": iPhone 6".
 "os_version": "iOS 10.x",
 "rabbit_build": "2.11.llyu",
 "resolution": "Fixed",
 }
```

With this kind of structure you could check all the values without loops by straightly getting value of "resolution" key

Comment: How can make change when it is already in a loop?


     `for ib in data['documents']:
     sid = ib['id']
     tit = ib['title']
     stat = ib['status']
     nstep = ib['next_step']['action']
     requester = ib['requesterIdentity']
     resolution = ib['customFields']['string']
     print(sid, tit, stat, nstep, requester, resolution)`

Comment: Check my latest update in question section which already runs in a loop. Is it possible to add another loop within a loop and print along with?

Comment: edited my answer, yeah, you just add one more loop to to through "string" list

Comment: did my best to explain what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Your present code don't do what you want because you are storing in a new variable called "resolution" the whole list in ib['customField']['string'] and print the value of this new variable.  (what is 'ib' ?)

There is no relation whatsoever between the name of this new variable and the behavior of the '=' operator.

You are trying to grab a specific element of the list, check if the 'id' contains 'resolution' then print it.

you can use

```
resolutionList = [it for it in ib['customFields']['string'] if it['id'] == 'resolution']
for element in resolutionList :
  print(element['value'])
```

or (in one line)

```
print(*[it['value'] for it in ib['customFields']['string'] if it['id'] == 'resolution'])
```

The * operator is used to deplete the list (print(*[a,b]) <=> print(a,b))

Comment: when the resolution is printed, it should be displayed with other loop values

Comment: no need to edit my answer, simply replace ib['customFields']['string'] in my syntax by the variable name i.e. resolution

Comment: "when the resolution is printed, it should be displayed with other loop values"  this doesn't mean anything